# The odd one out amongst odd ones out

Tags: cipher, knowledge, odd-one-out

For this task you will be presented four lists consisting of eight items. All items consist of two parts. To make things slightly easier for you, the length of the shortest part is given.

In each list the items share a common theme; your task is to identify the odd one out. Once you have completed this task, you may notice that all the odd ones out again share a common theme. Identify the odd one out once more and notice how that fits in with the grand theme of this puzzle.

I trust I have informed you sufficiently. Good luck!

### LIST 1: MOVIES

```
CRFMCBAN (6)  
KOZFTMVBOUS (8)  
LGHFNCE (4)  
LSRHWE (5)  
MRXX (4)  
VDOJION (4)  
VTZXRVOIR (4)  
YXDVHXNED (6)
```

### LIST 2: INFLUENTIAL PEOPLE

```
AFESCWOOD (5)  
DFHZPSGTON (6)  
DMUSFKSON (6)  
IZHZGE H W (4)  
MKFDWMA (7)  
QCSNDK (5)  
QJRFIAM HOWARD (4)  
UTVBEJY (6)
```

### LIST 3: SONGS

```
BFBSY (4)  
HTELYY (5)  
KDGAEGIAN (4)  
MSYYWTACK (6)  
OTAPQYE (5)  
RZCE (3)  
RZNYPOINE (6)  
WULCMOR (5)
```

### LIST 4: FICTIONAL CHARACTERS

```
EGOWEEDORE (5)  
LSWUWUS (5)  
OTOSLEY (3)  
OWSAPTFE (7)  
QSMIDY (5)  
XPLLDR (5)  
XZRHOR (3)  
ZTJPNAYTOM (7)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I notice straight away that

> The items are only enciphered up to the number of letters in the smaller, hidden part. For example, in `EGOWEEDORE (5)`, the first five letters of the word are enciphered and the rest are not.

This means that even without knowing the cipher, I was able to work out a lot of these right off the bat, and from that I was able to work out that the cipher is

> Simply adding the letter values of the smallest word to those of the biggest word. To use the same example, `EGOWEEDORE (5)` is Albus Dumbledore:
>
>  `D(4)  + A(1)  = E(5)`
>  `U(21) + L(12) = G(33-26=7)`
>  `M(13) + B(2)  = O(15)`
>  `B(2)  + U(21) = W(23)`
>  `L(12) + S(19) = E(31-26=5)`

I won't write out the sums for every single item (at least, not right now), but here are the deciphered items:

**Movies:**

> CRFMCBAN (6) = American Beauty
>  KOZFTMVBOUS (8) = Inglourious Basterds
>  LGHFNCE (4) = True Romance (credit to @Wa Kai)
>  LSRHWE (5) = Jackie Brown
>  MRXX (4) = Kill Bill
>  VDOJION (4) = Pulp Fiction
>  VTZXRVOIR (4) = Reservoir Dogs
>  YXDVHXNED (6) = Django Unchained

The odd one out is

> American Beauty, as it wasn't directed by Quentin Tarantino

**Influential People:**

> AFESCWOOD (5) = [Frank Underwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Underwood_(House_of_Cards))
>  DFHZPSGTON (6) = George Washington
>  DMUSFKSON (6) = Thomas Jefferson
>  IZHZGE H W (4) = George H W Bush
>  MKFDWMA (7) = Abraham Lincoln
>  QCSNDK (5) = Barack Obama
>  QJRFIAM HOWARD (4) = William Howard Taft
>  UTVBEJY (6) = John F Kennedy

The odd one out is

> Frank Underwood, who is a fictional character - the rest are all real US Presidents

**Songs:**

> BFBSY (4) = Penny Lane
>  HTELYY (5) = Space Oddity (credit to @hexomino)
>  KDGAEGIAN (4) = Norwegian Wood
>  MSYYWTACK (6) = Paperback Writer
>  OTAPQYE (5) = Hello Goodbye
>  RZCE (3) = Hey Jude
>  RZNYPOINE (6) = Yellow Submarine
>  WULCMOR (5) = Eleanor Rigby

The odd one out is

> Space Oddity because the rest are all Beatles songs

**Fictional Characters:**

> EGOWEEDORE (5) = Albus Dumbledore
>  LSWUWUS (5) = Severus Snape
>  OTOSLEY (3) = Ron Weasley
>  OWSAPTFE (7) = Hermione Granger
>  QSMIDY (5) = Draco Malfoy
>  XPLLDR (5) = Harry Potter
>  XZRHOR (3) = Lex Luthor
>  ZTJPNAYTOM (7) = Neville Longbottom (credit to @Wa Kai)

Which makes the odd one out

> Lex Luthor, as he's the only one not from Harry Potter

So we now have

> American Beauty, Frank Underwood, Space Oddity, and Lex Luthor

I noticed that

> Kevin Spacey was in American Beauty, played Frank Underwood in House of Cards, and played Lex Luthor in Superman Returns

Which means the odd one is

> Space Oddity - it has 'space' in it, but no Kevin Spacey

It fits the theme of the puzzle because

> Being the odd one out, it's an 'oddity'.

Comment: The last missing movie must be 'True Romance' and 'Neville Longbottom' for the characters

Comment: I would have worked out "True Romance" myself a few minutes ago had my Internet not crashed when I tried Googling Tarantino's filmography. Added those now.

Comment: @F1Krazy Space Oddity?

Comment: Well done, by the way, +1!